# How to shift all the active work flows to processbuilder?

Tags: process-builder

There are 36 active workflows for the opportunity and I want to shift to process builder is anyone has an idea how to shift. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good resource to start is the Trailhead [Workflow Rule Migration](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/workflow_migration). It will give recommendations directly from Salesforce.

I just want to add that for Field Updates the validation rules are triggered in Process Builder, unlike Workflows. So probably you will start to see a lot of error emails in your inbox.

Finally here is the link for the session [5 Essential Techniques For Successful Coexistence Of Clicks AND Code](https://www.salesforce.com/video/7822221/) by Daniel Stange with recommendations for using declarative tools like Process Builder with existing automation.

Comment: Thank you @ElkCor

Comment: @SaiSrinivas The SFSE way is to thank those who've helped you by upvoting their answers or, better, accepting them with the green check mark if they solved the problem for you.